# capitalization of the word section, theorem,... if refering using both number and adjective/name

Tags: capitalization, mathematics, academia

I have a question related to [Capital letters in "Theorem", "Conjecture" etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189196/capital-letters-in-theorem-conjecture-etc), [Capitalization of "Theorem 1" in mathematics papers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/capitalization-of-theorem-1-in-mathematics-papers), https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27693/capitalization-of-theorem-names, but a bit more specific.

In academic writing, it is common to capitalize the first letter of words like chapter, section, theorem etc. when refering to them by their number. (E.g. "See Theorem 1.3.2 in Section 1.3"). Otherwise, one should use lower case letter (such as in "As a consequence of the last theorem,..." or "In the following section..."). Somewhat a gray zone are named theorems, such as Pythagorean T/theorem (but I guess it is more common to use lower case letter).

But what if I want to combine those approaches. For example, "From Stone–Weierstrass Т/theorem 1.2.3 it follows that..." or "We will get back to this in (the) last S/section 3.5 of this chapter".

I guess that, from a language perspective, it is not a very good style. It would be better to write either "last section" or "Section 3.5" and, if need, write something like "in the last section (Sect. 3.5)". But on the other hand, I find it useful for the reader to see both the references (they might not remember, what was mentioned as Thm. 1.2.3, but they know Stone–Weierstrass theorem, or they do not know Stone–Weierstrass theorem, so they might want to look it up in the text) and I think it is good to keep the text consise without unnecessary repetitions.

So I am asking: How bad do you think it is to write it like this? If it is acceptable, should I capitalize the first letter or not?

Comment: Have you read G Edgar's answer at the thread you first mention? That said, individual institutions often have arbitrary preferences, and you should abide by the rules laid down by the relevant authority. Others don't have to.

Comment: Well, such special questions are usually not treated in any styles. At least I did not find it. Nevertheless, I believe it is good to follow _some_ style or at least some intuition or inner logic behind those rules and not to invent own rules arbitrarily. Since I am not a native English speaker, a lot of those rules are not very intuitive for me and hence it is hard to extrapolate the rules to some special cases.

Comment: That's the point: if you needn't follow an in-house style guide, the 'rule' is given by G Edgar. _Different educated Anglophones do things in different ways._ Find a style you like, and use it consistently.